# Accessing Instance Variable from Controller In View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, view, instance

I am very new to Rails so this will probably seem basic to most of you.  I am having trouble getting instance variables from one of my controller methods to show in my view.  I am trying to get the first 10 entries of a MySQL table called Odds to show up in a table on my index view.

Here is my Model:

```
class Odds < ActiveRecord::Base

# select odds for all games
def self.index_odds
    find(:all, :limit => 10)
end
end
```

Here is my Controller:

```
class OddsController < ApplicationController
def index
@index_odds = Odds.index_odds
end
end
```

Here is my View:

```
<h1>Odds#index</h1>
<table border = "1">
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>matchid</th>
<th>typeid</th>
<th>spread_home</th>
<th>spread_away</th>
<th>spread_home_lay</th>
<th>spread_away_lay</th>
<th>home_total</th>
<th>away_total</th>
<th>total_lay</th>
<th>moneyline_home</th>
<th>moneyline_away</th>
<th>moneyline_lay</th>
<th>hteamid</th>
<th>ateamid</th>
</tr>

<% for odds in @index_odds %>
<tr>
<td><%h odds.id %></td>
<td><%h odds.matchid %></td>
<td><%h odds.typeid %></td>
<td><%h odds.spread_home %></td>
<td><%h odds.spread_away %></td>
<td><%h odds.spread_home_lay %></td>
<td><%h odds.spread_away_lay %></td>
<td><%h odds.home_total %></td>
<td><%h odds.away_total %></td>
<td><%h odds.total_lay %></td>
<td><%h odds.moneyline_home %></td>
<td><%h odds.moneyline_away %></td>
<td><%h odds.moneyline_lay %></td>
<td><%h odds.hteamid %></td>
<td><%h odds.ateamid %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>

</table>
```

The only thing that is showing up is the table heading.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks okay so I'm going to guess that somehow @index_odds is empty. Your code looks like it's doing everything correctly so I would drop a `p` or even a ruby-debug gem's `debugger` command if you're feeling especially saucy.

Edit: Crikey, you forgot the = in `<%= h`

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Wow I am blind that fixed it.